# Putting 2cm granite on top of plywood and adhensive

Tags: framing, adhesive, countertops, granite

I posted a question here about my idea for outdoor granite countertop:

[Granite countertop installation on top of 4x4 outdoor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/97118/granite-countertop-installation-on-top-of-4x4-outdoor)

I found a 2 cm countertop piece (without the thick L-shape edges) as it's just flat on all 4 sides. You could say it's unfinished but since the sides are all shiny, I like it the way it is.

If I put it on outdoor plywood and glue using granite adhesive, is that enough? I am afraid the piece still moves because the 4 sides don't have the thick edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could reinforce the edge/rim with a strip (steel, hardwood, or 2x4s) underneath the plywood.

Brackets should also be helpful, especially if they are attached to support strips.

Comment: But do you think there is problem with "sliding" especially someone leaning against the granite? Let say 2 people leaning while talking. I think the granite is heavy enough plus the glue. But I can't tell.

Comment: I understand the the countertop is too thin for sink bolts or other more permanent solutions. Glue should hold it, until it starts to fail. In my experience, glue sometimes only lasts a few years in a wet environment (there are many kinds/qualities of glue). For this application it may last longer if the wood is sealed/painted (moisture protected). If/when the glue does give way, you will probably want/expect to replace the plywood, so be sure to consider replacement in the building design (ie., use screws instead of nails, and don't glue the plywood to the post or brackets).

Comment: Have you considered alternatives (like 2x4s) instead of plywood?